# “undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass” in youtube tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

so I was looking at various options to implement a session shopping cart after it was mentioned by a friend and found a video on youtube.. Few minutes into the code and there's an `undefined method "title" for nil:NilClass` error and I can't seem to figure out why it came about and how the tutor was able to solve it.

Here's the view code:

```
<% @cart.each do |id, quantity| %>
<% product = Product.find_by_id(id) %>
    <%= link_to product.title, '#' %>
<% end %>
```

Here's the controller code:

```
  def index
    if session[:cart]
      @cart = session[:cart]
    else
      @cart = {}
    end
  end

  def add
    id = params[:id]

    if session[:cart]
      cart = session[:cart]
    else
      session[:cart] = {}
      cart = session[:cart]
    end

    if cart[id]
      cart[id] = cart[id] + 1
    else
      cart[id] = 1
    end

    redirect_to :index
  end

  def empty_cart
    session[:cart] = nil

    redirect_to :index
  end
```

Now, the tutor was able to solve(without giving an explanation -.-) this noMethodError simply by adding `<%= link_to "Empty Cart", cart_clear_path %>` at the top of his view code. Now programming is logic and not magic, so I'm curious as to how that worked but I can't seem to come up with an explanation. Every help is welcomed

NB: This is the link to the [Youtube Tutorial](https://youtu.be/HSMqi913SL4?list=PL5Dq9xKbrI3CZRfqbyyesEvyYg-ivIPUq)

Comment: Haven't watched the video, but this must mean that cart is corrupted (contains product id that isn't in the database. By clearing the cart, we get rid of this rogue id and error disappears.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I thought in that direction too then tried this which worked `<% @cart.each do |id, quantity| %><% product = Product.find_by_id(id) %><p><%= product %></p><% end %>` and it printed out the objects that are present in cart but when you call an attribute on these objects, the error is thrown